# How to determine whether element is clickable or not?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

My Question is How to check whether the element is clickable or not ?.Is there any method to chat that like isElementVisible() or IsElementPresent() and etc ... Please let me know if one is having a knowledge about this problem. My scripting language is javascript+Node.js and using selenium webdriver

Comment: Enabled means it is clickable.

Comment: No, every enable element is not clickable say example after login Hello text is there even it is is enabled but it is not clickable

Comment: So you want to know which elements are links or buttons? Or more general: Which elements trigger an action after you clicked it?

Comment: if element is not clickable then no need to check for click I think..

Comment: Yes @ Twaldigas , right now my requirement is I know which are clickable elements but i want make sure that before clicking the element , that element is clickable

Comment: Your test should not simulate mad monkey clicking on anything clickable. How would you know if result is correct? Instead, it should click on known elements, and confirm desired result of that action. @Yamikuronue has your correct answer, if you understand what automated testing is.

Answer (score 4):

You can click text. It just (usually) doesn't DO anything. Everything that exists CAN be clicked -- you can move your pointer over it and click the mouse. Whether the application does anything with that click event is up to the logic behind the page, which Selenium can't help you with because it doesn't know how your application works.

An example with clickable text: https://jsfiddle.net/xqnxkhuw/ (click the words in the lower-right panel to see it in action)

So what you're after is really domain knowledge, which we can't help you with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Yamikuronue, Here my goal is not clicking  the text or button etc. I am trying to find whether element is clickable element or non-clickable element.

Comment: But everything can be clicked. What do you mean by "clickable"?

Comment: everything can be clicked but some of them only having  actions to perform by clicking . I want to find that elements

Comment: Then my answer does apply. Webdriver has no idea what parts of your application ought to have interactions. That's domain knowledge.

Comment: +1. Most frustrating is situation when OP is so beginner s/he does not understand when answer is correct.

Comment: @ Yamikuronue  , Yes what you said is partially correct in my scenario but what I am asking is say example "Login Button " is available I know that is clickable but i want to make sure that before clicking the button that button is clickable or not

Comment: @Peter Masiar . how would you know that OP required answer ,there is a chance of mis-understanding the OP's post .So please dont frustrate

Comment: Then nobody understands what you mean. We asked if you meant enabled and you said no. What exactly do you mean by click able then?

Comment: Now I understand **why** I was not able to understand the question, and why OP does not understand the answer. I promise I will not frustrate. :-)

Comment: @Yamikuronue Be kind, this is a good question, even if it could use a little more detail. FYI the OP is referring to Selenium's notion of "clickable" which comes up in the WebDriver error `Element is not clickable at point...`. Not being "displayed" is only one of several reasons this might occur. Another reason is when there is another element (spinner/splash) overlaid which would instead receive the click. Or when the element is scrolled off-screen. Further discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error

Comment: @SamuelJaeschke This question has been closed for *three years*.

Answer (score 3):

I do this test as little different way.I am using exception of wait.You can also use more time for wait object.

```
//Code written in Java
public static boolean isClickable(WebElement webe)      
{
    try
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(yourWebDriver, 5);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webe));
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Call this method in your class.

Example :

```
boolean bst = className.isClickable("your element");
```

If bst is true then element is clickable otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

This is only valid if Element has disabled property in HTML DOM.

You have to check whether the element has "disabled" attribute.

Read more on that here:

- [HTML  disabled Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp)
- [Textarea disabled Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_textarea_disabled.asp)
- [HTML  disabled Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_fieldset_disabled.asp)

Comment: This only while you have disable attribute/Property in HTML code

Answer (score -2):

**First Solution** : By default you cannot find the element is click able or not you must have to perform click action on that element and after clicking on the element check any unique locator after click event perform.

**Second Solution** : check the element tag name

```
String tagname=driver.findElement(By.id("id")).getTagName();
```

if it is button then check it's attribute is not disabled. then it is click able.